# Car icon on marker moving sideways flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-markers

I am working on a ride hailing application where I need to move a car-like icon along a poly line on my map. However, the car-icon doesn't move smoothly across the polyline. It just glides sideways in an ugly way. how do I ensure the best experience?

```
 Marker driverMarker = Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('endMarker'),
        position:driverLatLng,
        zIndex: 1,
        flat: true,
        rotation: positionEnd.heading,
        anchor: Offset(0.5, 0.5),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: 'Destination',
          //snippet: ' $_placeDistance km',
        ),
        icon:
        startIcon, //BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueOrange),
      );
```

Comment: is it ugly in production mode as well, or only in the WM during development?

Answer (score 0):

Until date, [GoogleMapsFlutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) does not support `navigation`. By simulating navigation yourself, you cannot get a perfect result for sure. Apps like Uber or Lyft are in *partnership* with GoogleMapsApi letting them use navigation as App built-in feature. Also, Google Maps Api when asked for DirectionsRoute, **does not always provide a straight path** in order to shorten the returned result, mostly when your route contains many turns. So when you draw the polyline on Google Maps Flutter, it is not always straight and your users cannot have perfect result.